# Declaring a javascript object literal in Script#

Tags: javascript, jquery, script#

I am trying to replicate a jquery ajax call in Script# and in the data option I am passing an object literal

```
{ id: target.data("id"), name: newName}
```

I am trying to reproduce this in Script#, but I am currently unsuccessful.  The first thing that came to mind was an anonymous object:

```
new { id = target.GetDataValue("id"), name = newName }
```

but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

`new Dictionary("id", target.GetDataValue("id"), "name", newName)`

or

`Script.Literal("{ id: target.data(\"id\"), name: newName}")`

Both should translate to your original code more or less.

Comment: The Dictionary option works great.  The Script.Literal option will not work because target.data("id") is a variable and to use Script.Literal the string has to be a constant string.

Comment: You can use Script.Literal (though its not a preferred option) as follows: Script.Literal("{{ id: {0}, name: {1} }}", target.GetDataValue("id"), newName) ... HTH